# Adding newline character in string (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, char, newline

How to add a new line character to a string in Matlab for the equivalent Java code?

```
String line;
line += "\n";
```

Comment: Try `line = strcat (line, char(10))`

Answer (score 6):

From  below links

```
str = sprintf('test \n test')
or 
str = ['test ' char(10) ' 'test']
```

1. [strcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html)
2. [Inserting_Newlines_into_Disp_Warn_and_Error](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Inserting_Newlines_into_Disp_Warn_and_Error)
3. [how to add a newline symbol into a string?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270680)

Comment: The second option should be str = ['test ', char(10) ,'test']

Answer (score 2):

"newline" depends on the operating system you are using... the best solution is

```
line = sprintf('%s\n', line);
```

This will force Matlab to use the "right" carriage return for the OS.